# Using append to create an overlay in a jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, append

I am trying to make a small jQuery plugin that is able to create an overlay to create a tinting effect.  To create this overlay is simple enough using plain js & jQuery, but when I try to wrap it all up into a jQuery plugin I get the error message that append (and appendTo) are not functions.  The plugin works if I use extend instead of append, but the it is simply changing the existing css code, while I want to create an actual overlay over any div or object.

```
(function ($) {

  $.fn.tint = function( options )
    {
      var overlay = $.append(
        {
          backgroundColor: "black",
          opacity: 0.5,
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
          position: "absolute",
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          //"z-index": 1000,
        }, options
      );
      return this.css(
        {
          backgroundColor: overlay.backgroundColor,
          opacity: overlay.opacity,
          width: overlay.width,
          height: overlay.height,
          position: overlay.position,
          top: overlay.top,
          left: overlay.left,
          right: overlay.right,
          bottom: overlay.bottom,
          //z-index: overlay.z-index,
        }
      );
    }
} ( jQuery ));
```

Comment: How do you intend to use this?

Comment: I am hoping to make a small plugin that will create an opaque black overlay over any element on a page to create a simple tinting effect similar to this:  http://jsfiddle.net/youngstoic/57cu83hx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do `$.extend` (not `$.append`):

```js
(function ($) {
        $.fn.tint = function( options )
        {
  
          if($(this).find(".overlay").length > 0) return $(this);

          var overlay = $.extend({
              backgroundColor: "black",
              opacity: 0.5,
              width: "100%",
              height: "100%",
              position: "absolute",
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              bottom: 0,
              //"z-index": 1000,
            }, options);
    
          $("<div class='overlay'>").css(
            {
              backgroundColor: overlay.backgroundColor,
              opacity: overlay.opacity,
              width: overlay.width,
              height: overlay.height,
              position: overlay.position,
              top: overlay.top,
              left: overlay.left,
              right: overlay.right,
              bottom: overlay.bottom,
              //z-index: overlay.z-index,
            }
          ).appendTo(this);
          return $(this);
        }
    } ( jQuery ));
    
    $(".overlay-target").on("click", function(){
        $(this).tint({backgroundColor: "green"});
    });
```

```css
.overlay-target {
   border: 1px solid red;
   margin: 20px;
   padding: 50px;
   position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='overlay-target'>I want an overlay</div>
```

Comment: well I have found some examples of doing this on JSFiddle, and when you write it as a stand-alone function the append works just fine.  My problem is using it in a plugin.
http://jsfiddle.net/youngstoic/57cu83hx/
http://jsfiddle.net/youngstoic/ec128wmt/

Comment: You want to "extend" your options with the default ones, then use the merged values to apply as css properties to the element. This answer will just work fine if your intention is this. If you are after something else, let me know.

Comment: When I use this as a plugin it does not overlay the css properties, but instead merges them together.  So when I use the method it causes everything inside of the jquery selected object to become opaque, instead of adding an opaque layer over it.

Comment: can you show your initial code before you converted it to a plugin which works as expected?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/youngstoic/57cu83hx/
when you click on the text it will add a green overlay.  It doesn't remove the previous background color, but instead overlays an opaque background color over it.  So if you where to change the bodies background color and do it again, the color will be different.
So I'm hoping to make a small plugin that can easily create a "tinting" effect, but can also be customized with different colors and opacity.

Comment: are you doing this for the whole body or to a specific selector?

Comment: I would like to be able to do it for a specific selector.  But ultimately, I would like it to be able to work for both.

Comment: oh wow that looks great!  I tried using a css id earlier too, but I wasn't able to figure it out.
I cant test it out at this exact moment, but I can in about an hour.  Thank you for your help Taha!